# Initialising date with Date(milliseconds) constructor

Tags: java, date

JavaDoc for Date class states that

```
public Date(long date)
Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of         
milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970,   
00:00:00 GMT.
```

Below is the code which calculates Date for Jan 24th and Jan 25th by calculating the number of milliseconds using Date(long milliSeconds) constructor

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.text.ParseException {

    long milliSecFor25 = (24*60*60*24*1000);
    long milliSecFor26 = (25*60*60*24*1000);
    Date dateJan25 = new Date(milliSecFor25);
    Date dateJan26 = new Date(milliSecFor26);
    System.out.println("Date for Jan 25:" + dateJan25);
    System.out.println("Date for Jan 26:" + dateJan26);
}
```

On executing the below code i get the below output,

```
    Date for Jan 25: Sun Jan 25 05:30:00 IST 1970
    Date for Jan 26: Sun Dec 07 12:27:12 IST 1969
```

which is incorrect. Can someone explain why don`t I get the correct date for Jan 25

Comment: I think you should check your use of "ambiguous" for future reference - I think you just mean "incorrect" here, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ya okay thanks and i will change it here too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
25*60*60*24*1000
```

All of this is being performed in *integer* arithmetic - and that value is overflowing.

You can see that if you perform the arithmetic using `long` values instead, and show the result compared to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
milliSecFor26 = (25*60*60*24*1000L);
System.out.println("Millis: " + milliSecFor26);
System.out.println("Integer.MAX_VALUE: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Prints:

```
Millis: 2160000000
Integer.MAX_VALUE: 2147483647
```

So your `int` arithmetic is actually overflowing to a *negative* value, which is why you're seeing a `Date` value before the Unix epoch.

As asides:

- You can use `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(26)` as a much cleaner way of computing this
- Within the Java standard libraries (pre-Java 8), you should use `Calendar` to obtain an appropriate `Date` from a year/month/day
- [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) is a *much* nicer library than `Date`/`Calendar`
- Java 8 will have an [even cleaner date/time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (in the `java.time` package).

Answer (score 6):

You're having an integer overflow. Use longs instead of ints:

```
long milliSecFor25 = (24L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 1000L);
```